# Node express, import module 404

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

When trying to import modules into `app.js`, I am getting a `GET <URL> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` error message.

This was previously working with `require` and browserify.

```
import * as KYC from '../../../build/contracts/KYC.json';
import * as Web3 from '../../node_modules/web3';
import { timeConverter } from './utils';
```

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/html/entry.html');
});

function userIsLoggedIn() { return true; }

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Here is the folder structure

[image: folder structure]

Any advice on how to fix this, or what should be done differently is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `import` isn't valid syntax and not supported by Node unless you're running it through something like Babel.

Comment: @Marlorn app.js is client side JS

Comment: My bad.  Is the client-side JS getting transpiled using Babel, etc.?

Comment: @Marlorn, no it is not

Comment: So the issue still stands then: `import` isn't valid syntax unless it gets transpiled using something like Babel.

Comment: @Marlorn, ES6 isn't native to the browser?

Comment: I guess I'm dating myself, apparently `import` [_is_ supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=javascript%20modules) on the client now (_back in my day_ they weren't...).  Sorry for leading you astray.  Back to your problem: are you sure that all of your import paths resolve correctly?  Are the imports wrapped in `<script type="module"></script>`?